# DisTube not showing Song name and requested user

Tags: javascript, discord.js, distube

Distube is not showing the name of the song and the user who requested it. It shows the duration though. Any idea why?

Code:

```js
client.distube
    .on("playSong", (song) => message.channel.send(
        `Playing \`${song.title}\` - \`${song.formattedDuration}\`\nRequested by: ${song.user}`
    ))
```

Output:
[image: output]

Comment: The [documentation](https://distube.js.org/#/docs/JS-DisTube/v2/class/DisTube?scrollTo=e-playSong)  says `song` is the 3rd argument in the function. Can you verify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the code [here](https://github.com/skick1234/DisTube/blob/v2/src/DisTube.js#L1081), the `playSong` event is emitted when a new song is played and has three parameters, namely

 
• `message` ( appends MessageObject from discord.js ) 
• `queue` ( your queue of songs ) 
• `song` ( this parameter contains your required values ) 

So in your arrow function listener it'd be something like

```js
client.distube
    .on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => { message.channel.send(
        `Playing \`${song.title}\` - \`${song.formattedDuration}\`\nRequested by: ${song.user}`
    )
});
```